# Project not finding packages.config dependencies

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application and i´ve installed all packages via the Nuget Package manager. Its working normally in my machine but when i checked in the build server throw me some errors:

[image: Build Errors]

In my packages.config i have all these packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
 <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net451" />
 <package id="AWSSDK" version="2.2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
 <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.3" targetFramework="net451" />
 <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net451" /> 
 <package id="jQuery" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="log4net" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net451" />
 <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
 <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
 <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net451" />
 <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
 <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
 <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Unity" version="3.5.1404.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net451" />
```

I tried to reinstall the packages via the NugetCommand line, but nothing seems to work. Is there someone that had this issue too?

Comment: Did you enable nuget on the build server as described in the [NuGet docs](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build)?